# Embedded SQL request

Tags: php, sql, date

I have a SQL Database. In here is a table called `Reports` and it looks like this

```
ID       Date            Year     Title            Links
1        2010-05-03      2010     Report 1         link1.php
2        2010-09-03      2010     Report 2         link2.php
3        2011-01-05      2011     Report 3         link3.php
```

What I'm trying to achieve it the this. I want to select all the reports of 2010-2011 but the ones from 2010 may only be those dating from september.

Right now, I've got a SQL statement selecting all the reports of the two years

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE Year = ".$db->escape($jaar1)." OR jaar = ".$db->escape($jaar2);
```

How can I select `Report 2` (cause it dates from september 2010) and `Report 3` (cause it dates from 2011)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way as I see it, is to use the [`BETWEEN...AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Reports`
WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '2010-09-01' AND NOW()
```

Note the backticks. Especially important around `Date`, because it is a reserved word.

Comment: Is this a correct request? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE 'Date' BETWEEN '".$db->escape($jaar2)."-09-01' AND '".$db->escape($jaar1)."-08-31'";`

Comment: Got it, this was the most simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `Date` column is of type `DATE`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `Reports`
 WHERE (YEAR(`Date`) = 2010 AND MONTH(`Date`) = 9)
       OR YEAR(`Date`) = 2011
```

Comment: `Date` is indeed of the `DATE`-type. You also mentioned `YEAR`. Is this the a part of the SQL statement of a reference to my `YEAR`column?

Comment: No, that's the MySQL `YEAR()` function which extracts the year part from a date. Seems to be the same as your `Year` column to me, but you may want to replace that expression with your `Year` column instead. I don't know what the difference is to you.

Comment: Ok, as far as I know, it works :) One question though, reports submitted in october (10), november (11) or december (12) will be requested too? Or how can I select every report as from the 9th month?

Answer (score 0):

general pattern

```
where year = 2011
or ( year = 2010 and month = 'September' )
```